# CSS not last child - cannot remove border of last grouping

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have these  groupings that each should have a bottom 1px border of red. There may be an unknown amount of these grouping. However the last grouping should not have a bottom border. What should the CSS sytax be to accomplish this?

```css
dl>.price-list:not(last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <div class="price-list">
    <dt>Tuition</dt>
    <dd>$10</dd>
  </div>
</dl>

<dl>
  <div class="price-list">
    <dt>Tuition</dt>
    <dd>$10</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

Comment: What have you tried (that's not working)?

Comment: dl {
  & > .price-list:not(last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid $c-gray-2;
  }
}

Comment: That's not CSS, it's LESS/SCSS, please [edit] the post and include the missing details

Comment: Sorry about that  dl > .price-list:not(last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the code that you tried, it's hard to see what is going wrong. I suspect you tried *not last child* but when there are other items following this list (of another tagName), that won't work. use `:last-of-type` instead.

Following your edit: first of all you forgot a colon before `last-child`. Second, you are selecting the last `.price-list` child, but in your HTML there is only one such item per `dl`. You are probably trying to select all but the last `dl` items, rather than `.price-list`.

```css
dl:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <div class="price-list">
    <dt>Tuition</dt>
    <dd>$10</dd>
  </div>
</dl>

<dl>
  <div class="price-list">
    <dt>Tuition</dt>
    <dd>$10</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
<dl>
  <div class="price-list">
    <dt>Tuition</dt>
    <dd>$10</dd>
  </div>
</dl>

<dl>
  <div class="price-list">
    <dt>Tuition</dt>
    <dd>$10</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
<dl>
  <div class="price-list">
    <dt>Tuition</dt>
    <dd>$10</dd>
  </div>
</dl>

<dl>
  <div class="price-list">
    <dt>Tuition</dt>
    <dd>$10</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code, it should do the work:

```
.price-list {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
.price-list:last-child {
    border-bottom: none
}
```